Kosher Wine and Other Spirits
The Talmud gives two reasons for the prohibition of gentile wines:

Gentile wines are at risk of use for Avodah Zarah.
Gentile wines risk intermarriage: "And they issued the decree prohibiting their wine due to the fact that this leads to familiarity, and Jews will come to marry their daughters." (Avodah Zarah 36b)

So even if we are guaranteed on who is not idol worshipper has produced the wine, we are not permitted to drink it due to the risk of intermarriage. Halachipedia concurs
:

"Muslims are not idol worshippers, so their wine and wine they touch
is only prohibited from drinking, because of intermarriage. Rishonim
and Acharonim unanimously voice this ruling."

So why aren't spirits and other intoxicants similarly prohibited? Are not the risks of "familiarity" just as present with vodka as with wine?

Tangentially related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92556/non-kosher-wine-and-rabbi-natan-shapiros-sefer-yayin-ha-meshumar

They are indeed also prohibited https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2263/759

as @DoubleAA says see also See Pninei Halocho  פרק כט – יין ומשקאות גויים 
“לאחר שאסרו חכמים יין, פת ובישולי גויים, הוסיפו האמוראים סייג נוסף בפני התבוללות, שלא ישתה ישראל משקה אלכוהולי בביתו של גוי או בחנותו או בבית הקפה שלו או בכל מקום שברשותו (ע"ז לא, ב). בכלל האיסור כל המשקאות האלכוהוליים כדוגמת ויסקי, ערק, וודקה, ליקר, בירה וכל כיוצא בזה. “

The prohibitions mentioned involve drinking with non Jews. None prohibit consuming their alcohol alone as is the case with wine. For example, I can buy vodka made from a goy and drink it at home, but I cannot take his wine. Why is vodka permissible?

No. Why can I drink beer made by goyim at all given that I cannot drink wine made by goyim regardless of the company and location even if they do not engage in Avodah Zarah. If its permissible for me to drink a goy's beer in my house it should be permissible for me to drink his wine in my house.

I'm also confused about why I am allowed to purchase mevushal wine from a Muslim but not normal wine given the intermarriage issue persists regardless of whether the wine is boiled. What's more so troubling is that Kosher wine is often used for communion so the reasoning behind mevushal as being protective against Avodah Zarah is invalid.
